# How to use a String returned by a Future<String> method in flutter?

Tags: flutter, future, flutter-desktop

I'm trying to read a json file's components using the following method:

```
import 'dart:io';

class CharacterDataReader {
  Future<String> read() async {
    final file = File('assets/data/character_data.json');

    String data = await file.readAsString();

    return data;
  }
}
```

Now, I'm trying to assign the read values to a String named data and json.decode() it in another class using the following:

```
Future<String> data = CharacterDataReader().read();
Map<String, dynamic> characterData = json.decode(data);
```

However, this doesn't work since json.decode() only accepts Strings as a parameter. Therefore, can someone please tell me how do I convert this Future into an actual string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since its a future you have to add await keyword

```
String data= await CharacterDataReader().read();
```

check out dart official doc on [asynchronous programming](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await)